# PNG image background blocks links, works on FF only

Tags: css, png

I have a navigation menu in one div and there's a background image in other div which is set to absolute because it has to be in some a bit different position of the website. Now that image is transparent PNG and it blocks clicking the last link in the navigation because that image is technically on top of that link (visually not).

So I set z-index: 1 to menu and that fixed the problem only on Firefox, the link becomes clickable. It doesn't work on Chrome, Opera and IE though.

What could be the problem?

There's a screenshot, as you can see that girl image is transparent and when selected it shows that it technically is over that Contact us link and it somehow blocks it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4rEV.jpg

The menu and the image are not in the same parent div.

```
#the-menu {
margin: 17px 0 0 17px;
z-index: 1;
}

#the-img {
background: url("../images/img-girl.png") no-repeat scroll center 0 transparent;
height: 351px;
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
top: -52px;
width: 381px;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's hard if you not give sample code.

Comment: added more details. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#the-menu` should have relative position in order for the z-index to work.